# Removedir function is not working

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I am new to inno setup so please forgive any ignorance. 
I am trying to delete a folder only if it's empty
Here is the script:

```
procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
begin
  if CurUninstallStep = usPostUninstall then
  begin
    RemoveDir(ExpandConstant('{userdocs}\Games'), True, True, True);
  end;
end;
```

This reruns an error:

> Invalid number of parameter.

I got (not the full code but some pieces) this from this site.
I have another question,does `RemoveDir` function check if the folder is empty or not?
I already read the documentation.
Please help.Thanks.

Comment: can you add the details of the error?

Comment: @ Ophir Yoktan I updated the answer. Someone  please help!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_removedir) the function gets only a single parameter:

> **Prototype:**
>
> ```
> function RemoveDir(const Dir: string): Boolean;
> ```
>
> **Description:** Deletes an existing empty directory. The return value is True if a new directory was successfully deleted, or False if an
>   error occurred.

Comment: @YoktanI  I add that before `procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);` this showing begin expected whats now?

Comment: I think i need to do something with `, True, True, True);` line. Someone please help.

Comment: @Kushal, what help shows are the function prototypes. There you can read how the functions are defined. Here you can see that it's a function that returns `Boolean` and that its only parameter is called `Dir` which is of type `string`. You're just calling that function from your script. With a proper number of parameters, types and understanding what they mean. It's not a trial error process. Btw. what you have somehow badly copied seems to be the call of `DelTree` function.

Comment: @TLama Please post a example of `RemoveDir`, what you are talking it going over my head.Please I don't know pascalcode very much.Thanks for your time .

Comment: @Kushal, no, I won't. You'd be just copy pasting code into editor. That would have no benefit for you. It's not about I don't know Pascal Script. You rather don't want to know. It cannot be easier. There are thousands of function call examples all over there. Take a look at how e.g. the `MsgBox` function is called from script and look how it's described in help as a prototype. This is how every programming language describes the functions.

Comment: @TLama I googled `RemoveDir` function before posting the question but i do not find any helpful artical,only create directory .so i post this question about how to use `RemoveDir ` function So please help.I have nowhere to go.

Comment: @TLama I really can't make this function working .please any response.

Comment: @TLama why are you calling me as _"Kushal"_?

Answer (score 0):

Ah Finally I have solve it myself and find the error reason.OH that was a headache, I was just stuck. 
I just need to remove `true;`

**Here is the full code:**

```
procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
begin
  if CurUninstallStep = usPostUninstall then
  begin
    RemoveDir(ExpandConstant('{userdocs}\Games'))
  end;
end;
```

Now it is fully working.

**THANKS EVERYONE FOR YOUR HELPS.**